# ROC curves with BlueSky Statistics

Tags: statistics, roc

I'm just beginning to explore the capabilities of BlueSky Statistics. I read in a review that ROC curves are among the available graphics but I cannot find them in the menus. Is it possible to draw them in BlueSky and also to get AUC and Youden's index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlueSky does not yet overlay ROC curves, so you would have to do one model for each of your independent variables, then follow Val's answer. Overlaying ROC curves is on the roadmap for future versions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see ROC curves, you need to first create a model. You can create it using any of the dialogs under Model Fitting. Then on the top right hand corner of the screen, select the model and click the score button. We will automatically show you the ROC curve and the ROC table if applicable. The dependent variable must have 2 levels for a ROC curve to display

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I created a model of logistic regression with 4 independent variables. The program produces a single ROC curve, which I suppose is the cumulative one. Is there a way of obtaining 4 separate curves in the same graphic?